# Enthalpy in a non-reversible isobaric process

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, physical-chemistry, reversibility

I know that in a *reversible* isobaric process, the enthalpy change of the system is the change in heat for that system. What happens if the process is not reversible? I.e *only* the outside pressure is constant, for example atmospheric pressure?

For example, in a container with a movable piston on the top, a gas phase chemical reaction takes place with ΔH, in an uncontrolled manner so that the process is irreversible. The outside pressure is atmospheric. Is still ΔH=Δq for the gas (assume in the reaction the moles of gas are not changed)? The initial and final pressures are the same for the reacting gas then.

Answer (score 3):

In all cases, reversible or not, we have $\Delta U=-P_e\Delta V+Q$ or $$(U_f+P_eV_f)-(U_i+P_eV_i)=Q$$ (with $P_e$ the external pressure.)

If there is pressure equilibrium for the initial and final states $P_i=P_e$ and $P_f=P_e$ we have $$(U_f+P_fV_f)-(U_i+P_iV_i)=Q$$ i.e. $\Delta H =Q$

Comment: Why $\Delta U=-P_e\Delta V+Q$ is true in any process?

Comment: It is simply the first principle of thermodynamics. Always valid.

Comment: The value of $Q$ is different in reversible and irreversible processes, no? Then in isobaric process $\Delta H=Q$ will be different?

Comment: @VincentFraticelli You're assuming $Q = TdS$ but that only holds in the reversible case. Hence isobaric $\Delta H = TdS = Q_{rev} > Q_{irr}$ since $Q_{irr} < TdS$

Comment: I don't see where I am assuming $Q=TdS$ ?

Comment: @VincentFraticelli Because isobaric $\Delta U = W + Q =- P_e\Delta V + \int T dS$. So by claiming $W = P_e\Delta V$, you're implying $Q = \int TdS$. Or, as a differential -- since isobaric $dU = \delta W + \delta Q = -P_e dV + TdS$, then by claiming $\delta W = -P_e dV$ you are implying $\delta Q = TdS$. But again, $Q = \int TdS$ and $\delta Q = TdS$ *only* apply in reversible cases, not the *irreversible* one requested by the OP...

Comment: @VincentFraticelli Also I think you have to explicitly put at "@" before my username otherwise I won't see your replies in my inbox. And, I'm missing an integral symbol [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/760874/enthalpy-in-a-non-reversible-isobaric-process/760921#comment1796525_760921) which should say, isobaric $\Delta H = \int TdS = Q_{rev} > Q_{irr}$ since $Q_{irr} < \int TdS$ (per [Clausius inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem) $\delta Q < TdS$ for irreversible processes)

Comment: @ManRow Sorry for the missing @ ! $W=-P_e\Delta V$ is simply   $W= F_e\Delta x=P_e S\Delta x$ with $S \Delta x=-\Delta V$ and do not assume reversibility at all.

Comment: @VincentFraticelli See [this answer by hyportnex](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/760875/168695) in the same thread. However, it's possible that the [Clausius inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem) was *misused there* hence isobaric $dH = \delta Q$ for all cases (i.e, by the very *definition of entropy* per $dS = \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ such that *your* answer correctly simplifies $$dH = TdS = T\left(\frac{\delta Q}{T}\right) = \delta Q \Rightarrow \boxed{H = Q} $$ whereas hyportnex "misapplies" the Clausius inequality **altogether** for where it is not relevant at all).

Comment: @ManRow This result depends only on the first law and does not involve the second law of thermodynamics.
This result is used systematically in the case of chemical reactions which are most often not reversible. The local distribution of pressure and temperature within an explosive chemical reaction is certainly not uniform and the application of the relationship $dU=TdS-PdV$ can only be local.

Comment: @VincentFraticelli It's not so much about the uniformity -- just a matter of *consistency* ensuring that the "$TdS$" term always refers to either $T_{sys}dS_{sys}$ or $T_{surr}dS_{surr}$, not any "mixed" products like $T_{surr}dS_{sys}$ that arise from the Clausius inequality. As long as that consistency is followed, we have $TdS = \delta q$ simply just from the "definition" of the entropy itself (so, no need to actually invoke anything from the Second Law of thermodynamics or Clausius's Theorem at all). This ensures $\Delta H = Q$ as you stated.

Comment: @ManRow What do you call $T$ and $P$ for a system whose temperature and pressure vary from one point to another?

Comment: @VincentFraticelli You pick a convention that's convenient to use but it must be *consistent* and properly "applicable" to the scenario. For this isobaric case, we can simply pick the external pressure $P = P_e$ (this is what an isobaric process implies anyway -- a constant $P_e$). As far as the temperature and entropy goes, in this case, it wouldn't matter since $\delta q = T_{sys}dS_{sys} = T_{surr}dS_{surr}$ anyway regardless of reversibility/irreversibility.

Comment: @VincentFraticelli  Or, am I misunderstanding your question? Were you asking for a more *general* case?

Comment: @ManRow No, this is the usual case for chemical reactions: most often the temperature and pressure during the reaction are not uniform. On the other hand, they are uniform once thermodynamic equilibrium is reached. This is why I think it is not a good idea to use the thermodynamic identity for the whole system because the global values ​​of $P$ and $T$ are not defined during evolution. If we invoke the postulate of local thermodynamic equilibrium, very often valid, we can define these quantities locally and apply the thermodynamic identities to the local quantities (specific internal energy).

Comment: @JimmyYang $\Delta U = Q - P_{ext}\Delta V$ is not "true in any process". It is **only** true for *isobaric* processes because $P_{ext}$ is constant so we can say $W = -P_{ext}\Delta V$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $dU=TdS-pdV$ between two nearby equilibrium states you also have $dH=d(U+pV)=TdS-pdV + pdV+Vdp=TdS+Vdp$, and noting that $TdS \ge \delta Q$ *always*, you get $dH\ge \delta Q +Vdp$. Again, this is true irrespective of any process connecting the two equilibrium states. If you also assume that the pressure is the same at the end state as it was at the beginning, $dp=0$, you immediately get $dH\ge \delta Q$ with equality if and only if the process is reversible. If the process is irreversible then $dH > \delta Q$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $dH\le \delta Q$?

Comment: Just to inform innocent readers, I have argued with Jimmy Yang below in his own post why he is wrong.

Comment: @hyportnex But the first law of thermodynamics actually states $dU = \delta Q - \delta W$. So if you're saying $dU = TdS - PdV = \delta Q - \delta W$, then doesn't $\delta Q < TdS$ (for irreversible processes) imply $\delta W < PdV$ as well? But that would only makes sense if $P$ is the internal pressure for expansion (meaning the system actually does less work than its internal pressure would suggest), and the external pressure for compression (meaning less work is done onto the system than the external pressure would suggest). But shouldn't $P$ should refer to the *same thing* in all cases??

Comment: @ManRow denote the *external pressure* by $p_x$ against which the *system* delivers work $\delta W$, that is by definition $p_xdV$, this can only happen if $p_x <p$ where $p$ is the internal pressure that pushes the piston out.

Comment: @hyportnex But in an irreversible isobaric ***compression***, the internal pressure $p$ must be *less than* $p_x$, or else there is no "compression" of the system to be had at all! Right? Or, is there no such thing as an irreversible isobaric *compression*? Since that would require $p < p_x$...

Comment: @hyportnex Also compared to a reversible isobaric expansion, you have to apply *more heat* to an "irreversible" isobaric expansion to account for new entropy generation as well (i.e, so both can still do the same amount of overall net "work"). So if the start and end points of the two isobaric expansion processes are the same, then they will have the same enthalpy $\Delta H$. But, we had to add more heat to the irreversible one (to account for new entropy generation), so therefore $\Delta H_{both}=Q_{rev}<Q_{irr}$, which is the *opposite* relationship of what you stated in your answer instead.

Comment: @ManRow do not forget that when the internal energy is defined by engineers as $dU=\delta Q - \delta W$ then $\delta W$ is defined to be positive when the system does work *on* the environment, this is the case when $p_x <p$, the system *expands*, but when $p_x > p$ then the environment does work on the system with $\delta W <0$ and the system is compressed.

Comment: @ManRow you have misunderstood the meaning of the inequality $TdS > \delta Q$. $ \delta Q$ is the communicated heat or better said the net entropy absorbed by the system from the reservoir at temperature $T$ is $\delta S_x= \frac{\delta Q}{T}$. This  $\delta S_x$ entropy is less than the total entropy increase in the system at temperature $T$ which is $dS > \delta S_x$, so that $TdS>\delta Q$ because the irreversible process internally produced $dS-\delta S_x$ entropy and that much stays in the system and becomes part of its enthalpy, sometimes called the "heat content".

Comment: @hyportnex I see, so then does that "extra" $TdS−\delta Q$ also raise the internal energy of the system as well? Since $dU=TdS-PdV>\delta Q-\delta W$ if $\delta Q<TdS$ but $\delta W=PdV$ is a strict equality..

Comment: @ManRow yes, it does, Entropy is the agent of thermal work and is just entropy irrespective of its genesis, it is now part of the "thermal energy" portion $TS$ of $U=TS-pV+N\mu+...$. It can be used to produce work in a thermal engine if it can be transported to a lower temperature than $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the internal pressure.

If $P_i = P_f = P_{ext}$, then $\Delta H = Q$ regardless of reversibility (even if $\Delta S_{univ} > 0$).

If $P_i \ne P_f = P_{ext}$, then you could even have $Q = 0$ (adiabatic) and $\Delta H = \gamma W \ne Q$.

Answer (score -2):

In a reversible process, the change in the system's entropy caused by (reversible) heat flow $Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}$ is

$$\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}=\frac{Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}}{T}$$

In an irreversible process, the change in the system's entropy caused by heat flow $Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}$ is

$$\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}=\frac{Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}}{T}+\Delta S_\mathrm{univ}$$

where $\Delta S_\mathrm{univ}$ is the change in the universe's entropy. This relation can be rewritten in terms of $Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}$:

$Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}=T\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}-T\Delta S_\mathrm{univ}=Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}-Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out} \tag{1}$

where $Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out}$ is spontaneous heat released by the system caused by irreversible process.

For an isobaric process, the change in enthalpy is

$$\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta (PV)=\Delta U+P\Delta V$$

by the first law of thermodynamics $\Delta U=Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}-P\Delta V+W_\mathrm{other}^\mathrm{on}$ where $W_\mathrm{other}^\mathrm{on}$ is *any* non-$PV$ work done on system,

$$\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}+W_\mathrm{other}^\mathrm{on}$$

It seems like your question does not assume the existence of other forms of work, so

$$\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}$$

According to (1), for any reversible processes $\Delta S_\mathrm{univ}=0$:

$$\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}$$

and for any irreversible processes:

$$\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}-Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out}$$

So, enthalpy change satisfies the following inequality:

$$\Delta H\le Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}$$

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your notation is so confusing that it caused you to get it wrong. Just look at $\mathrm d S = \mathrm d S_\text{rev} + \mathrm d S_\text{irrev} \geqslant \mathrm d S_\text{rev}$ and get $\mathrm d H = T \mathrm d S + V \mathrm d p \geqslant T \mathrm d S_\text{rev} + V \mathrm d p = \mathrm d H_\text{rev}$.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I don't think that's right because  $dS$ in $dH=TdS+VdP$ is $dS_\mathrm{sys}$, entropy change of a *system* not universe. Also, I never seen $dS = \mathrm d S_\text{rev} + \mathrm d S_\text{irrev}$ before. It should be $dS=dS_\mathrm{sys}+dS_\mathrm{surroundings}$. Reversible processes refer to any process where $dS=0$, ie. $dS_\mathrm{sys}=-dS_\mathrm{surroundings}$.

Comment: You are just plain wrong in your understanding of what those equations are doing. The generation of the entropy in an irreversible process happens within the inside of the system. We are basically never trying to quantify the entropy generation in the surroundings. At most we would be pushing the excessively generated entropy from within the system to outside of the system. The textbooks you are using are talking about a totally different thing. They are analysing the combined system + surroundings undergoing processes, so that then $dS=dS_\text{sys}+dS_\text{surroundings}$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Sorry, I don't get what you are trying to say and I don't see where I am wrong here. From your equation $d S = \mathrm d S_\text{rev} + \mathrm d S_\text{irrev}$, it looks like you are implying that if the process is reversible, then $dS=dS_\mathrm{rev}$ which is odd. How it is possible for the entropy of the universe to increase during a reversible process?

Comment: The entropy of a system alone can increase in a reversible process by getting it from the environment. $\mathrm d S_\text{rev} = đ Q / T$ is the famous formula. If you only ever consider system+surroundings then you cannot get this formula anywhere in your equations because the contribution from the surroundings would cancel that from the system. It is, after all, a reversible exchange of entropy. Then your universe can only change entropy value by irreversible increases.

Comment: In other words, my $\mathrm d S = \mathrm d S_\text{sys}$ and your $\mathrm d S = \mathrm d S_\text{univ}$. The choice you are using is very confusing because we only ever consider the reservoir = surrounding = environment to be so large that even non-quasistatic, i.e. fast processes cannot change its $p , T, \mu$ i.e. the reservoir can only do reversible changes, even quickly. Then $\mathrm d S_\text{univ} = \mathrm d S_\text{irrev}$. I will leave you to sort out the paradoxical equations this bad choice causes. The choice that is more common is mine, precisely because it is clearer.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent So you are saying this equation $\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}=\frac{Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}}{T}+\Delta S_\mathrm{univ}$ is wrong?

Comment: I wanted to point out that you are wrong about the fact that $d H = T \mathrm d S + V \mathrm d p \geqslant T \mathrm d S_\text{rev} + V \mathrm d p = \mathrm d H_\text{rev}$ because $dS$ in $dH=TdS+VdP$ refers to $dS_\mathrm{rev}$, so $dH\le dH_\mathrm{rev}$.

Comment: Yes, I think that should be wrong. The issue is whether $Q^\text{in}_\text{net} = Q^\text{in}_\text{rev}$ because there is no way to get the net version otherwise. All we may properly deduce is the reversible part.

Comment: You cannot be seriously claiming that $\mathrm d H_\text{rev} \neq T \mathrm d S_\text{rev} + V \mathrm d p$. That would be an incredibly confusing notation. It can only be $\mathrm d H = T \mathrm d S_\text{rev} + T \mathrm d S_\text{irrev} + V \mathrm d p = \mathrm d H_\text{rev} + T \mathrm d S_\text{univ} \geqslant \mathrm d H_\text{rev}$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent $TdS$ term in thermodynamic identities *always* refer to reversible heat flow.

Comment: That is a _choice,_ and it is clearly a confusing one that basically no other textbook is choosing to use, precisely because the notation I am using is so much clearer and impossible to make mistakes upon. The least confusing choice of viewpoint that most physics textbooks use is the one whereby we only focus upon what is happening to the simple ideal gas system we are studying. If you want to do something else, you can, but do not claim to speak for the rest of the world.

Comment: Not to mention that if you truly believed that $T \mathrm d S$ always refers to reversible heat flow, then for goodness you cannot get $T \mathrm d S \geqslant T \mathrm d S_\text{rev}$ that you yourself used.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I am confused whether $\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}=Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}-Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out}$ or $\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}+Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out}$.

Comment: I do not know what happens to the entropy generated irreversibly. Is it removed from the system or not? That depends upon the specific process, and thus it can be taken of either sign. Yes, that contributes to the confusion possible here. But what we generally do not assume, is to think of it as heat. Because the generated entropy can well not be in the form of heat, even though it can be removed as if it were heat. This is particularly obvious in the case of adiabatic free expansion, because no heat is generated nor exchanged there, only purely entropy.