# Does the change in enthalpy $\Delta H$ equals to the total amount of heat flow in a system?

Tags: thermodynamics

After answering [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/760874/enthalpy-in-a-non-reversible-isobaric-process/760876), I am now confused about whether the change in enthalpy equals the total amount of heat that flows in a system:

$$\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{net}^\mathrm{in}=Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}-Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out}$$

or the total amount of heat that flows in and out a system:

$$\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}+Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out}$$

where $Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}$ is the amount of reversible heat flow in a system and $Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out}$ is the amount of irreversible heat released from a system. @hyportnex's answer seems to imply the latter because of the inequality $dH\ge\delta Q$ (note: I interpret $\delta Q$ here as reversible heat flow in) which implies

$$dH=TdS=T(dS_\mathrm{rev}+dS_\mathrm{irrev})=TdS_\mathrm{rev}+TdS_\mathrm{irrev}\ge\delta Q$$

or in my notation

$$\Delta H=Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}+Q_\mathrm{irrev}^\mathrm{out}\ge Q_\mathrm{rev}^\mathrm{in}$$

I am not sure which one is correct.

Edit:

It seems like this question boils down to whether the $TdS$ terms in thermodynamic identities like $dU=TdS-PdV$ refer to reversible heat flow only:

$$TdS=TdS_\mathrm{rev}$$

or both reversible and irreversible heat flow:

$$TdS=TdS_\mathrm{rev}+TdS_\mathrm{irrev}$$

Comment: Are you assuming constant pressure? $dH=dQ=TdS$ is true only at constant $P$.

Comment: @Themis Yes that's right and assume that no other forms of work are done.

Comment: @"no other forms of work done" does not mean $P$ is constant. In fact constant pressure means that there is $PV$ work involved.

Comment: @Themis I mean $\Delta H=Q+V\Delta P+W_\mathrm{other}=Q$ is true when pressure is constant and no other forms of work is done.

Comment: Check out @Vincent Fraticelli's answer to the earlier question, which is both simple and correct.

Comment: @JimmyYang Yes, but none of this is in your question, one has to guess that that's what you are assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few issues with this question that need to be corrected:

- What you call $Q_\text{irrev}$ is really entropy generation. So let's calculate entropy generation for constant pressure heating from $T_1$ to $T_2$ using a heat source at $T_3\geq T_2$: The entropy change of the system is $\Delta S_{12}$ and of the heating source $-Q/T_3$, and since $Q=\Delta H$ (since constant pressure), we have
  $$
     S_\text{gen} = \Delta S_{12} - \frac{\Delta H}{T_3}
  $$
  So now we have the final result in the form
  $$
     \Delta H = T_3\Delta S_{12} - T_3 S_\text{gen}
  $$
  This looks like the equation that you have written but it is not the same because $T_3\Delta S_{12}$ is not $Q_\text{rev}$. Also notice that the temperature in this result is not that of the system, which changes, but of the heat source.
- It doesn't make sense to write $T dS = T dS_\text{rev}$. All thermodynamic differentials, including $dU=T dS - P dV$, are relationships between thermodynamic properties, and these properties have an unambiguous value only in equilibrium, i.e., when $T$, $P$ and $\mu_i$ are uniform throughout the system.

Comment: Thank you 1. I am wondering can I understand $Q=\Delta H$ as reversible heat flow $Q_\mathrm{rev}$? 2. Is it meaningful to interpret $T_3S_\mathrm{gen}$ as heat released from system?

Comment: $Q=\Delta H$ is obtained assuming that heating is done reversibly *with respect to the system itself*, i.e., heating is slow enough that $T$ and $P$ are always uniform. The *overall process* may still be irreversible, if for example we are using a heat source whose temperature is different from that of the system. This is the irreversibility that causes $S_\text{gen}$. This is not heat released by the system, it is work that could have been produced (but was not) had we run the overall process reversibly.

Comment: One more thing, $S_\mathrm{gen}$ is equal to the entropy change in universe right?

Comment: Yes: $S_\text{gen}=\Delta S_\text{sys}+\Delta S_\text{surr} = \Delta S_\text{univ}$